# char *str and malloc'ing the memory for str, still getting SEGFAULT

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, segmentation-fault

I have written a small C program to reverse a string.
In this even though, I declare the `str` as
char *str
and then
`str = (char*)malloc(20);
str = "this is a test";`
However, I wont get SEGFAULT if I use
`char str[20] = "this is a test"`

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 

void swap(char *a, char *b)
{ 
  char temp; 
  temp = *a;
  *a = *b; 
  *b = temp; 
} 

char* reverse(char *str)
{ 
  int len = strlen(str); 
  printf("len = %d \t %s\n", len, str); 
  int i = 0; 

  if (len == 0) 
    return NULL; 
  for (i=0; i<len/2; i++) 
  { 
    swap((str+i), (str+len-1-i));    
    printf("%s\n", str); 
  } 
  return str; 
} 

int main(void)
{ 
  char *str; 
  str = (char *)malloc(20); 
  str = "this is a test"; 

  printf("%s\n", str); 
  reverse(str); 
  printf("%s\n", str); 
  return 0; 
}
```

My understanding was I will get SEGFAULT, if I declare,
`char *str="This is a test"`  becuase it will be a constant string.
So, I thought, when, I malloc, `str` will be allocated from the heap and heap memory will accessible to both the functions. But,
still get the SEGFAULT error.

Comment: `str = (char*)malloc(20); 
     34         str = "this is a test";`...LEAKKKKKKK

Comment: `str = "this is a test";` --> `strcpy(str, "this is a test");`

Comment: Your compiler isn't warning you about the dangerous assignment of a string-literal pointer (i.e. `char const *`) to a modifiable string pointer (`char *`).  You need to turn your warning levels up (or use a compiler that will warn you).

Comment: BTW, [don't cast the return value from `malloc()`](/q/605845).

Comment: Next time don't put line numbers into your code, post the code as is.

Comment: `return NULL;` --> `return str;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do

```
str = (char*)malloc(20);
str = "this is a test";
```

you *reassign* the pointer `str` to point somewhere else right after the allocation.

In fact you make it point to a string literal, which is an array of *read-only* characters. Attempting to modify a string literal leads to *undefined behavior*.

The simple solution is to use arrays instead. Or to *copy* into the memory you allocate using [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy).

Answer (score 5):

Well, there are differences between a pointer (pointing to a string literal) and an array, they are not the same. [Check the C-FAQ for arrays and pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/) for more insight on this.

First of all,

```
  str = (char*)malloc(20); 
  str = "this is a test";
```

causes memory leak, as you're overwriting the pointer returned by `malloc()`. This case, `malloc()` can be simply removed, as you're not storing anything to the memory location pointer to by the `str`, rather you are storing the base address of the unnamed `const char` array in the pointer variable.

Later, when you try to pass the pointer to the string literal and try to alter the content, you invoke  [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as string literals are read-only and attempt to alter them causes the UB.

On the other hand, you don't see the problem while using a `char` array, because, the array content is modifiable.

Answer (score 1):

```
 str = (char*)malloc(20);
 if(NULL != str)
 memcpy(str,"this is a test",(strlen("this is a test") + 1));
```

Comment: "*the constant string address is local to that function*" <- what? oO

Comment: Now it's a code-only answer without any explanation and using `memcpy()` here is a) needlessly complicated (that's what `strcpy()` is for) and b) wrong like shown (doesn't copy the `0` terminator). Appreciate your willingness to give answers, but this is unfortunately a bad one.

Comment: Also the the last argument should be `MIN(20, strlen("this is a test"))` (even after ignoring the copy of `\0`)

Comment: How does this get upvoted? The code shown **is wrong**. The result of this is not a string and OP's code will treat it as one.